# How do I display a dynamically selected ionicon?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6, ionicons

I have a small button that's meant to be some sort of close button with a somewhat dynamically-selected (i.e., pickable at runtime) image, for placing in toolbars.

`close-button.component.html`:

```
<ion-button (click)="click()">
    <ion-icon [ios]="ios" [md]="md" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

`close-button.component.ts`:

```
// snip imports, @Component
export class CloseButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public click: () => void;
    @Input() public direction?: string;

    protected md: string = 'close';
    protected ios: string = 'close';

    constructor() {}
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        if(this.direction) {
            this.ios = 'chevron-' + this.direction;
            this.md = 'arrow-' + this.direction;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the icon doesn't show up unless `direction` is falsy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what value is showing up for this.direction?

Comment: If I do something like `<app-close-button [click]="fun">` it shows a cross. If I do `<app-close-button [click]="fun" direction="left">` it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is not with your dynamic selection, it is with your icons. always check the icons docs if you want to use ionic icons. `Chevron` and `Arrow` have `up`, `forward`, `down` and `back` direction, not left and right.

```
<ion-icon name="chevron-forward"></ion-icon>
```